# Filtering Options for an RTL-SDR (DSP and Analog routes)

Tags: filter, signal, radio, signal-processing, dsp

I have several related questions regarding filtering for an RTL-SDR radio. It's readily swamped by the very, very strong AM and FM radio stations local to me. So much so that your basic passive RC circuits do absolutely nothing to attenuate them.

**1.** I'm considering implementing some kind of DSP solution for this - passing the antenna's signal into some kind of chip that would completely filter out the AM and FM bands.
The Sampling theorem says I would need to be able to sample at twice the highest frequency the RTL-SDR is capable of receiving in order to be able to perfectly handle the incoming signals.
If I understand that right, since the RTL-SDR has a max frequency of 1.75 GHz, I would need to be able to sample at at least 3.5 GHz.

I don't know of any microcontroller that goes anywhere near that high in clock speed, let alone actual sampling ability. And that's just for ADC, not even considering DAC once the filtering's been done.
Would I have to do this on an FPGA, then?

**2.** if I wanted to instead implement this with active op-amp filters, something tells me I can't just get something for nothing. There needs to be a gotcha somewhere that would limit it.

I'm thinking this would be the highest speed at which the op-amp could switch at? If it can't switch as fast as the highest input frequency, it'll distort them, right?

**3.** Would it be possible to perfectly filter out an offending signal in a radio by, say, having a time-identical but 180-degrees-out-of-phase duplicate of the incoming radio signal, bandpassing the frequencies I don't want in the out-of-phase signal, then combining this signal with the unaltered signal so that the bandpassed unwanted signals destructively interfere with the same signals in the final output?

Comment: What frequencies are you interested in? Say, 144Hz (2m amateur band) as an example. Then build a tuned RF amplifier that boosts the 2m band and attenuates the FM band, and insert that between antenna and SDR. Signal processing won't help once a broadband front end has allowed interference to stomp all over the wanted signal by overloading the first mixer (or ADC)

Comment: Well, I was hoping I would be able to just get rid of the entirety of the AM and FM bands while leaving the rest of the bands intact. (I might have an idealized view of DSP since most of my practical knowledge comes from music production).

I wanted to make best use of the entire 500 kHz-1.75 MHz the RTL-SDR claims to support, but the AM/FM bands cause a wideband rise in the noise floor of at least -10 dB, and also cause artifacts to pop up at multiples of the FM/AM station frequencies.

So, I'll just have to boost the frequencies I want to hear, rather than removing the ones I don't?

Comment: You can try implementing a band stop filter in your RF front end to eliminate these bands : it's likely to be more complex and poorer performance than a tuned bandpass (or several to cover different bands). See what you can get out of a tuned RF amp; that can serve as a benchmark for bandstop or other approaches.

Comment: I have passive AM and FM band-stop filters on the front end, but they hardly put a dent in either. I don't think the roll-off is steep enough to do much of anything in terms of attenuating.
That's why I was toying around with the idea of active band-stop filters in 2. Though at that point my knowledge of filters drops off and it's the wild west. I'll have to do some heavy reading if it's even feasible (and not a completely stupid idea).

Comment: Are those L-C filters? R-C filters will do nothing, but high order L-C filters should help.

Comment: They're R-C filters. I was extremely skeptical that they would do anything when buying them, but who knows - they had a neat metal enclosure and maybe they had some magic dust that my capacitors didn't have. (They didn't). I'll look into replacing them with some LC filters.

Comment: It is also possible for L-C filters to attenuate those bands, but the interference still bypasses them thanks to poor grounding and/or circuit layout practice. Look into using RTL-SDR for spectral analysis and measure the input frequency response with/without those filters.   Are they achieving the attenuation specified in the datasheet? (this is still worth doing with the R-C filters, as a way to see what's happening instead of staying in the dark)